# Storage permission

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, android-permissions

I'm getting this message that is logged after trying to lunch device storage to choose an image, keep in mind that even if permissions are handled in the code I don't the prompt asking the user to allow. for camera use it asks without any problems.

its a simple web Socket app that allows users to send messages or attachments, then it will be upgraded to include text and so on.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4DE.png

check my code below I know there is some repeated code, its cuz I checked my guides but ended up mixing some things so please if there is something not needed tell me

this is the message from console
2023-08-07 08:55:56.818  3492-3492  MainFragment            com.example.websoc                   D  Launching gallery intent...
it logs that the lunch but never got any prompt, it enters the function as shown from the log.

```
companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
        private const val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1

        private const val PERMISSION_CODE = 1001
    }

 private lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String
    private var selectedImageUri: Uri? = null
private fun setupPermissions() {
        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
        )

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission denied")
        }
    }

// this is in onViewCreated
   val galleryButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.galleryButton)
        galleryButton.setOnClickListener {
            openGallery()
            requestGalleryPermission()

        }

  private val galleryActivityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Gallery intent result: success")
                val intent = result.data
                intent?.data?.let { uri ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Selected image URI: $uri")
                    // Handle the selected image URI here
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Gallery intent was canceled or failed.")
            }
        }



private fun requestGalleryPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Gallery permission granted. Launching gallery intent...")
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                requireActivity(),
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                PERMISSION_CODE
            )
        }
    }
 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Gallery permission granted. Launching gallery intent...")
                    val intent =
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                    galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Gallery permission denied.")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun openMenu() {
        val galleryButton = view?.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.galleryButton)

        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(requireContext(), galleryButton)

        // Inflate the menu resource
        popupMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.gallary_menu, popupMenu.menu)
        // Set a listener for menu item click events
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_gallery -> {
                    // Handle the gallery menu item click here
                    Log.d("MainFragment", "Launching gallery intent...")
                    requestGalleryPermission()
                    true
                }

                R.id.menu_cam -> {
                    // Handle the "Open Camera" menu item click here
                    openCamera()
                    true
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }
        popupMenu.show()
    }
```

Comment: You got an uri. Use ot to upload your image. You do not need awkward things like get real path from uri.

Comment: I get type mismatch

Type mismatch.
Required:
File
Found:
Url

Comment: Where do you get that without showing your code. Do you think we know what you did?

Comment: I tried but its to long to fit in the comment !

Comment: One does not put code in comments. You will use your post to put your code.

Comment: I made some significant changes due to a bug ill update my question

Comment: check the updated one please

Comment: the issue has been fixed when I updated my compile sdk to 33 and kept the target sdk to 32, it asks for permissions, but when tested again on the compile and target sdk 33 it doesnt, it seems its an sdk 33 issue ? right